# Run an atmega328 only using an 16Mhz crystal without caps

Tags: arduino, capacitor, atmega, crystal

Can you run an ATmega328 only using an 16Mhz crystal, so without the capacitors?

Comment: Even if your crystal doesn't require load caps, you should always have a ceramic bypass capacitor between power and ground as close as possible to a microcontroller.

Comment: Why would you want to go without the capacitors? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of - set the fuses so it runs off the internal oscillator and it shouldn't care what's connected to the xtal pins. You won't need the crystal either.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean a two pin crystal like this one

[image]

then the answer is no.  This type or crystal requires the two capacitors in order to oscillate.

On the other hand if you mean a 4 pin crystal oscillator like

[image]

then it can work fine because this is a complete oscillator that only needs power to generate the clock.
In order to use it you have to set the clock source of the AVR to external clock (CKSEL3..0 = 0000) and feed the clock signal to XTAL1 pin.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's generally a good idea to bypass canned-oscillators like the one in the second image with a 0.1 uF capacitor, though you may be able to get away without it.

Comment: Also, some MCUs have internal load capacitors for an external crystal, so they may not require *external* capacitors (Parallax Propeller MCU comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an external oscillator and the caps if you use the internal one (8MHz)

If you have an Arduino this might help: [Lower part](https://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try. You *might* get lucky thanks to stray capacitance in the prototype wiring and the pins of the CPU itself. Or it might not oscillate. Or it might oscillate at its 3rd harmonic; the CPU may not work reliably at 48 MHz.

Even if you do get lucky, when you move from a hand-wired prototype to a nice tight PCB, the stray capacitances will change and it will probably stop working...
So, not recommended.