# Programming ATMEGA1284p on internal 8MHz without caps

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, atmega, atmel

I'm trying to burn a bootloader on a standalone ATMEGA1284P without using caps or an external 16MHz crystal, just with a 100nF cap between GND and 3.3V VCC. I am using this bootloader from [maniacbug](https://github.com/maniacbug/mighty-1284p).
I am using the 8MHz bootloader from maniacbug.

I am burning the bootloader using an Arduino Uno, as described [here](https://www.electronicshub.org/burn-bootloader-on-atmega328/) using ArduinoIDE.

I've screened some related ressoruces already that could not help me:

[External oscillator or caps not required](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94608/run-an-atmega328-only-using-an-16mhz-crystal-without-caps)

[Built-in 8MHz crystal can be used](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/49296/can-i-use-atmega328p-without-capacitors)

[Internal 8MHz clock needs to be selected first.](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=93559.0)

I think [Nick Gammon](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches/blob/master/Atmega_Board_Programmer/Atmega_Board_Programmer.ino) also provides a bootloader but it is much more difficult to understand than the documentation of maniacbug.

I've double checked my wiring, it is correct, can you eventually help me in trying out the bootloader from Nick Gammon?

EDIT: I have also checked the [MightyCore bootloader](https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore) on 2 of my boards. It definitely supports internal RC oscillator.

Comment: What wiring you want us to check? So you are programming a bootloader to a complely empty AVR? With what programmer hardware and programming software?

Comment: @Justme I am using an Arduino Uno and ArduinoIDE, I've flashed bootloaders many times to standalone atmega1284p and atmega328p using that configuration but along with an external 16MHz cap and two load caps.

Comment: Could the bootloader have "fuses" or "configuration bits" set for external crystal oscillator? (Thus it won't run without one.) The text seems to prefer 16MHz and the Mighty 1284p - does that reference design use a crystal? If so, it won't work without recompiling.

Comment: realise there is no 'built in 8MHz crystal' - there is an 8MHz RC oscillator that has rather broad specs that vary with voltage and temperature. This makes reliable serial communications difficult. A zillion people have come to grief that way - just look at the forums. Arduino used a crystal for good reason.

Comment: @rdtsc I have also tried https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore on 2 boards without an external oscillator and couldn't flash bootloader onto them.

Comment: @Kartman is there a way to see If I can get any response of the Atmega1284p at all? By reading its fuses using avrdude or sth. like that.

Comment: If the fuses have been already set to expect an external crystal, it will not respond to anything unless the AVR is given a clock it expects.

Comment: If the AVR was previously fused for an external crystal, then you have to add an external crystal then you can change the fuses. I’m surprised you asked your question here as the problem you describe is so common, you’re probably the 10 millionth person to get caught by it. Just google unbrick avr.